# Can I add a new dimension/tag to the existing metric http_server_requests_seconds?

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, metrics, rest

I have a Java Spring Boot Application that is collecting metrics with Prometheus. It is a REST API and everything is working.

Spring, by default, provide some metrics. For example, the metric `http_server_requests_seconds_count` that has the dimensions:

```
http_server_requests_seconds_count{application="metrics-demo-app", exception="None", instance="host.docker.internal:8080", job="metrics-demo-app", method="GET", outcome="SUCCESS", status="200", uri="/actuator/prometheus"}
```

By dimension I mean the key/value pairs (*application="metrics-demo-app", exception="None",* etc...) tags in the example above.

Can I add a new dimension (key/value pair) to those metrics? My idea is when a call to create a user fails, to insert some more info into that metric.

I know that I could create a new custom metric, but I wonder if there are some manner to just add things in an existing one.

Is that possible? How to do that?

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done and how is in the documentation, here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.metrics.supported.system

My code ended like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MetricsConfig implements WebMvcTagsProvider {

  private final WebMvcTagsProvider delegate = new DefaultWebMvcTagsProvider();

  @Override
  public Iterable<Tag> getTags(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Throwable exception) {
    final String channelId = ServiceContextHolder.getContext().getXItauChannelId();

    return Tags.of(this.delegate.getTags(request, response, handler, exception)).and("channelId", channelId);
  }

  @Override
  public Iterable<Tag> getLongRequestTags(HttpServletRequest request, Object handler) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Note, that 'WebMvcTagsProvider' seems deprecated now and 'ServerRequestObservationConvention' should be used.